# Springboot application runs from uberjar but not from eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a springboot application that I can build using maven and then

java -jar target/jarfile.jar

and it runs.

I would like to keep it running in eclipse and update my thymeleaf templates rather than build and restart with every edit of a template

However, when I try to run from eclipse I get

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2020-06-21 09:40:40 INFO  Version:30 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-21 09:40:41 INFO  Application:55 - Starting Application on austin
2020-06-21 09:40:41 INFO  Application:651 - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-21 09:40:41 INFO  ChangeableUrls:225 - The Class-Path manifest attribute in /common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/ant/ant-optional/1.5.1/ant-optional-1.5.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/ant/ant-optional/1.5.1/xml-apis.jar,file:/common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/ant/ant-optional/1.5.1/xercesImpl.jar,file:/common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/ant/ant-optional/1.5.1/optional.jar,file:/common/home/xxx/.m2/repository/ant/ant-optional/1.5.1/xalan.jar
2020-06-21 09:40:41 INFO  DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor:225 - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-06-21 09:40:41 INFO  DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor:225 - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-06-21 09:40:42 ERROR SpringApplication:837 - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebSocketConfiguration.websocketContainerCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.pacificdataservices.diamond.apsweb.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'value' in annotation org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava should be compatible with org.springframework.boot.system.JavaVersion but a org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava$JavaVersion value was returned
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adaptForAttribute(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:500)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:426)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnJavaCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnJavaCondition.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'value' in annotation org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava should be compatible with org.springframework.boot.system.JavaVersion but a org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava$JavaVersion value was returned
` Are you using the same versions as what's in this über jar?

Comment: I believe it is asking about the jdk version.  Are you asking if my runtime jdk is the same version as the one that compiled the the source in the jar?  If so, I believe I am.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing jars from different spring or spring boot versions on your classpath. Which are resolved when packaging the jar, but still an issue in eclipse. (In my experience Eclipse is very bad in setting up a proper classpath from Maven or Gradle). So check your dependencies.